# question: How to generate new files with python in replit

Tags: python, random

I am currently working on a type of code generator for people making text games in python on replit so when people get off they can type in the code and start from where they were. If it is possible how would I do that, if not please just tell me a simple no.

ps:
The codes are generated via the random function

```py
code = random.randint(100000000, 999999999)
```

All I need is how to make the separate files with text inside them permanently.
Thank you for any help even if that is saying its not possible.

Comment: Thanks but the file creation works but the f.write doesn't work

Here is my code right now.
```python
n = input(str("What is your name?\n"))
code = random.randint(100000000, 999999999)
print("Welcome " + n + ", this is the beta test for ByteCycle")
print("your save code is: " + str(code))


f = open(str(code) + ".py","w+")
f.write("name = " + n)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say your best bet is to take your game save data, convert it to a string using the json module, and base64 encode it. Then you return that code to the user. This is because replit does not save files generated by the program, so by giving the data to the user to store, it keeps anything from attempting to save to the system.

Answer (score -1):

Here‘s my code:

```
f = open("file.txt","w+")
f.write(code)
```

Comment: Thank you so much this is exactly what I needed and it worked, now I can get this save system to work, I honestly thought this would be impossible but, no. I couldn't be more happy right now!

Comment: actually, the f.write(code) part won't work... It won't write the code and the file it blank.

This is what I have right now:

f.write("name = " + n )

Comment: @ProjectDucky It did not work since `code` is an `int`, you would need to cast it to `string` and then pass it `f.write(str(code))`

Comment: And it's also recommended to `close` the file or open it using the `with` context manager...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Thanks, I was looking through examples and found that out, my save system is working perfectly!